# How do you create footer columns on foundation 6.4?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying out foundation to make a website andI can't seem to get columns to work in the footer. I'm pretty sure I've used the correct CDN and imported everything correctly. The footer should have four columns.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hangout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/motion-ui/1.1.1/motion-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
          <h6>Laboratory</h6>
          <a href="http://www-act.ucsd.edu/maps/?mapid=459&wid=459&iws=true&cat=&t=Map&z=15&opacity=50&ll=32.879731,-117.236756&rand=92629" target="_blank">Canter Hall 3131</a><br>
          Biological Sciences and Bioengineering
        </div>
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
          <h6>SITE MAINTAINED BY</h6>
          <hr>
          A<br>
          B<br>
          C<br>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
          <h6>CONTACT LAB</h6>
          <hr>
          Phone: (999) 999-9999
          <br>
          <a href="https://www.google.com/">More Information</a>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
          <h6>AFFLIATIONS</h6>
          <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img1" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="40"></div></a></div>
          <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img2" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="40"></div></a></div>
          <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img3" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="40"></div></a></div>
          <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img4" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="75"></div></a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>



    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Foundation has [changed the way](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html) that the grid works in v6.4

> A fully reworked new grid system in v6.4 which has all the variety inbuilt in the form of multiple grid types which includes margin grid, padding grid, frame grid, block grid and vertical grid.

Replace `row` with `grid-x` on your row div:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- becomes: -->
<div class="grid-x">
```

And replace `columns` with `cell`:

```
<div class="medium-3 columns">
<!-- becomes: -->
<div class="medium-3 cell">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.2/css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/motion-ui/1.1.1/motion-ui.min.css" />
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <div class="row grid-x">
    <div class="medium-3 cell">
      <h6>Laboratory</h6>
      <a href="http://www-act.ucsd.edu/maps/?mapid=459&wid=459&iws=true&cat=&t=Map&z=15&opacity=50&ll=32.879731,-117.236756&rand=92629" target="_blank">Canter Hall 3131</a><br>
      Biological Sciences and Bioengineering
    </div>
    <div class="medium-3 cell">
      <h6>SITE MAINTAINED BY</h6>
      <hr>
      A<br>
      B<br>
      C<br>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-3 cell">
      <h6>CONTACT LAB</h6>
      <hr>
      Phone: (999) 999-9999
      <br>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/">More Information</a>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-3 cell">
      <h6>AFFLIATIONS</h6>
      <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img1" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="40"></div></a></div>
      <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img2" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="40"></div></a></div>
      <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img3" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="40"></div></a></div>
      <div><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><div class="logo_box"><img class="img4" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="75"></div></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

References:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.2/js/foundation.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.0/js/foundation.min.js